# Generate Swagger Documentation from Restlet based Maven Application

Tags: maven, swagger, swagger-ui, restlet

I am trying to use [Swagger extension](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/extensions/swagger) in restlet application which is using Maven.

The problem is when I change the inherited class from `org.restlet.Application` to 
`org.restlet.ext.swagger.SwaggerApplication` then it gives compile time error.

I didn't found any clue in the `Swagger extension documentation` on how to get rid of this compile time error.

Here is the error in eclipse -

[image]

I am using the following in versions of restlet in pom.xml -

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.swagger</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using java version 1.8.

**UPDATE:**

I got rid of compile time error with the correct dependencies as follows:-

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.swagger</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But now I do not get correct route to the swagger doc URL.

Here is the code-

```
    Router createUserRouter = new Router(getContext());
    createUserRouter.attach(createUserAPIName, CreateUserRest.class);
    rootRouter2.attach(createUserRouterName, createUserRouter); 

    Swagger2SpecificationRestlet swagger2SpecificationRestlet= new 
    Swagger2SpecificationRestlet(this);
    swagger2SpecificationRestlet.setBasePath("http://localhost:9546");
    swagger2SpecificationRestlet.attach(rootRouter2, "/api-docs");
    return rootRouter2;
```

I use the URL - `http://localhost:9546/api-docs`.
But I am getting `404 Not Found`.

Comment: Can you please explain how did you exactly solve the classfile not found error. I also have java 8 and am facing the same issue but i don't understand how to solve it.

Comment: i solved it. Can you please tell me if you found solution to last issue?